# How can I get paired coordinates from the implicite function?

Tags: equation-solving, implicit

I have equation E^y = x. How can I use Mathematica to solve all of "y" from the desired "x" value. For example, I want to solve for "y" from x = 0.5 , 1 , 1.5 , 2 , .... , 9.5 , 10. The solution should be (x=0.5 | y= -0.693) , (x=1 | y=0) , (x=2 | y=0.693) , ..... , (x=10 | y=2.302).

PS. Solving without algebraic technique e.g. Without taking Ln at both sides.
Because the real equation is quite complicated which cannot be solved. The equation above is just an example.

Comment: Do you want to run a minimization? It's not clear why you want it done *without algebraic technique*. Can you please explain better the context and what you are after? By the way, welcome to Mma.SE. Please follow this advice: taking the [tour] now,  learn about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers.

Comment: Because the real equation is quite complicated which cannot be solved.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain that there. Does it take long for your equation to evaluate? Don't make us guess the information necessary to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an numeric solution try

```
soly[x_] := Values@ NSolve[Exp[y] == x, y, Reals][[1, 1]] (*"solver"*)
Table[{x, soly[x]}, {x, 0.5, 10, .5}]
(*{{0.5, -0.693147}, {1., 0.}, {1.5, 0.405465}, {2., 0.693147}, {2.5,0.916291}, 
{3., 1.09861}, {3.5, 1.25276}, {4., 1.38629}, {4.5,1.50408}, {5., 1.60944}, 
{5.5, 1.70475}, {6., 1.79176}, {6.5,1.8718}, {7., 1.94591}, {7.5, 2.0149}, 
{8., 2.07944}, {8.5,2.14007}, {9., 2.19722}, {9.5, 2.25129}, {10., 2.30259}}*)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome!